# Highchart shiny R scatter plot - how to define individual point colors

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, scatter-plot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot in highcharts shiny R but I need to give a different color to points, individually. Consider for instance the following example:

```
library("MASS")

dscars <- round(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu = c(1, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2)), 2)


highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "scatter", zoomType = "xy") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(
    useHTML = TRUE,
    pointFormat = paste0("<span style=\"color:{series.color};\">{series.options.icon}</span>",
                         "{series.name}: <b>[{point.x}, {point.y}]</b><br/>")
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dscars)),
                marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("car")),
                icon = fa_icon("car"), name = "car")
```

My objective is to give to this 20 points, an unique color.

I tried to set the "fillColor" inside marker list as also as to define the color of the series, both with a vector of 20 colors but I had no success.

Can any one give me a hint?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In highcharts (the highcharter) the point can be given as other parameter, same as x and y. So first

```
library("MASS")

dscars <- round(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu = c(1, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2)), 2)
dscars <- as.data.frame(dscars)
names(dscars) <- c("x", "y") # it's better give a named list IMHO
dscars$color <- colorize(1:nrow(dscars))
```

`colorize`is a function to create a color vector given other vector. In this case the input vector is a sequence (no repeated) so the output will be differents colors. But if you want yo can use your own colors.

```
highchart() %>%
 hc_chart(type = "scatter", zoomType = "xy") %>% 
 hc_tooltip(
   useHTML = TRUE,
   pointFormat = paste0("<span style=\"color:{point.color};\">{series.options.icon}</span>",
                     "{series.name}: <b>[{point.x}, {point.y}]</b><br/>")
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(data = list_parse(dscars),
              marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("car")),
              icon = fa_icon("car"), name = "car")
```

Note we used:

- `color:{point.color};` in the poinFormat, beacuse every point has its own color in the color accesor.
- I used `list_parse` which parse the data frame in a named list instead of unnamed list so highcharts understand how to use the data. `list_parse` is the same `list.parse3` for old version of highcharts.

Hope it helps.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(highcharter)
library(MASS)
dscars <- data.frame(round(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu = c(1, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2)), 2))

highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(type = "scatter", zoomType = "xy") %>% 
  hc_tooltip(
    useHTML = TRUE,
    pointFormat = paste0("<span style=\"color:{colorByPoint:true};\">{series.options.icon}</span>",
                         "{series.name}: <b>[{point.x}, {point.y}]</b><br/>")
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dscars)),colorByPoint = TRUE,
                marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("car")),
                icon = fa_icon("car"), name = "car")
```

[image]

Comment: Be carefull with colorByPoint which uses the current colors of the theme. So if the number of points in more than the colors of the current theme there will be repeated colors.

Comment: I wanted to do a bit of JS but had to go home :(